# Should my python web app use unicode for all strings?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, unicode, pylons

I see some frameworks like Django using unicode all over the place so it seems like it might be a good idea.

On the other hand, it seems like a big pain to have all these extra 'u's floating around everywhere.

What will be a problem if I don't do this?

Are there any issues that will come up if I do do this?

I'm using Pylons right now as my framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 3, all strings are Unicode. So, you can prepare for this by using `u''` strings everywhere you need to, and then when you eventually upgrade to Python 3 using the `2to3` tool all the `u`s will disappear. And you'll be in a better position because you will have already tested your code with Unicode strings.

See [Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bit](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) for more information.

Answer (score 20):

You can avoid the `u''` in python 2.6 by doing:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

That will make `'string literals'` to be unicode objects, just like it is in python 3;

Comment: +1 It's too bad this can't be combined with the selected answer. They both are the 'best' answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 3):

> What will be a problem if I don't do this?

I'm a westerner living in Japan, so I've seen first-hand what is needed to work with non-ASCII characters. The problem if you don't use Unicode strings is that your code will be a frustration to the parts of the world that use anything other than A-Z. Our company has had a great deal of frustration getting certain web software to do Japanese characters without making a total mess of it.

It takes a little effort for English speakers to appreciate how great Unicode is, but it really is a terrific bit of work to make computers accessible to all cultures and languages.

"Gotchas":

1. Make sure your output web pages state the encoding in use properly (e.g. using content-encoding header), and then encode all Unicode strings properly at output. Python 3 Unicode strings is a great improvement to do this right.
2. Do everything with Unicode strings, and only convert to a specific encoding at the last moment, when doing output. Other languages, such as PHP, are prone to bugs when manipulating Unicode in e.g. UTF-8 form. Say you have to truncate a Unicode string. If it's in UTF-8 form internally, there's a risk you could chop off a multi-byte character half-way through, resulting in rubbish output. Python's use of Unicode strings internally makes it harder to make these mistakes.

Comment: Yep.  If you plan to do *any* kind of text manipulation (e.g. changing capitalization, chopping words into letters), use Python's unicode objects or you'll feel pain.

Answer (score 1):

Using Unicode internally is a good way to avoid problems with non-ASCII characters.  Convert at the boundaries of your application (incoming data to unicode, outgoing data to UTF-8 or whatever).  Pylons can do the conversion for you in many cases: e.g. controllers can safely return unicode strings; SQLAlchemy models may declare Unicode columns.

Regarding string literals in your source code: the u prefix is usually not necessary.  You can safely mix str objects containing ASCII with unicode objects.  Just make sure all your string literals are either pure ASCII or are u"unicode".